# how can access require.js module's function?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

i want to use a.js module's test();

my method:
**- a.js -**

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    function test(val) {
        alert(val);
    }
    window.test = test;
}
```

have other methods ? 
sorry my english very pool, I hope you can understand, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't usually assign to globals from a RequireJS module (i.e. set properties on `window`).

#### /path/test.js

```
define(function() {
    function test(val) {
        alert(val);
    }
    return test;
}
```

#### /path/app.html

```
<!-- import requirejs ... -->

<script>
// Use the return value from the "test" module.
require(["test"], function(testFn) {
    testFn("hello");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Clear, 3Q very much!you are handsome!

Comment: @user1817804 There, someone finally said it.